# Docker build failing during COPY command during Gradle build

Tags: docker, gradle, jenkins, dockerfile, ssh-keys

I'm attempting copy a private SSH key (file) onto my Jenkins image during a Gradle build.  My simple COPY in the Dockerfile is failing with the following error:

`#8 [3/5] COPY id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa #8 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref moby::t3o0ztz0sagnjtmsnde7vh23m: "/id_rsa": not found`

Here's my full Dockerfile.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11

COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt

COPY id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugin-file /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt

COPY seedJob.xml /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jobs/seed-job/config.xml

ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
```

Here's what I've tried.  Docker build WORKS when run as  `docker build -t testimage:1 .` so this is specific to Gradle.  I've tried moving my key to various locations/folders and (as you can se) it's currently in the same location as my Dockerfile.  I also tried the ADD command and got the same issue.  The really interesting thing is that its adding a "/" before it which is likely why it can't find it.  I tried adding an '.txt' file extension to it as well and that didn't help.  The name of the source is the issue.

**UPDATE**
After a few hours of wrangling, I came across the answer here -> [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74368688/dockerfile-is-unable-to-find-and-copy-local-file-when-building-image).  Seems all that was needed was to add to the 'files' section here in my build.gradle file. my assumption is all copied files or directories have to be declared there. Woohoo!

> docker {
> name "${project.name}:${project.version}"
> files "plugins.txt", "seedJob.xml", "MY_FILENAME_HERE"
>
> }

Comment: Do you have `/root/.ssh` folder on base image? Maybe there is a need to manually create it?

Comment: What's the build context that grader gradel sets? E.g. in `docker build .` the `.` is your context.

Comment: @TelinovDmitri I do not.  I figured the COPY would create it.

Comment: @BMitch Isn't that the folder I'm executing in?

Comment: From some sources (I am still unsure) - `COPY` is not creating the nested folders, maybe it is worth to try to do a `mkdir -p /root/.ssh` before that command?

Comment: Apologises, just have it from the documentation: 'If <dest> doesn’t exist, it is created along with all missing directories in its path.'

Comment: "Isn't that the folder I'm executing in?" If it was, you would be seeing the same error from the docker build command.

Comment: I’m literally running both gradle and docker build commands from the same location.  Is there a way to determine the context for gradle?

Comment: Try providing a [mcve] that includes a minimal Dockerfile, a dummy file to copy, any gradle files, and the commands run with their output.

Comment: You should be able to reproduce by grabbing the sample private key here [link](https://phpseclib.com/docs/rsa-keys) and saving it as 'id_rsa.  Then run a gradle build to create a docker image using the Dockerfile above.